# How can I find what the sample rate is if I measure it continuously for 100 times?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, frequency, sampling

I am using Adafruit ItsyBitsy, and an external ADS1115 ADC module.

I am continuously measuring the voltage using ADS1115 via loop 100 times.

```py
for i in range(0, 100): 
     analog_in = chan.voltage 
     analogfinal += analog_in
```

How can I know what the sampling rate of the loop is?

The ADS1115 can measure up to 860 samples per second and I2C @ 100kHz.

Why is it taking about a second to output the result even though ADS1115 can sample up to 860 per second?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the datasheet for the ADS1115?

Comment: Which of the Itsybitsy models? The M0 that can run Python?

Comment: Set an IO pin high before each sample. Then set it low after you get the data. Look at the IO pin on the oscilloscope.

Comment: Have you considered how many "time" take a complete "for...loop"?

Comment: How do you output the result? Is there a (slow?) serial line involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention any other settings you've made using the [Adafruit ADS1x15 CircuitPython library,](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15/releases) so I expect that means you are using the standard values.

The library uses a 128 Hz sampling rate and single mode in the default settings.

"Single mode" means that it requests one sample from the ADC each time you call "chan.voltage."  Your code has to sit and wait for one sample to be  made.

128 Hz means you get 128 samples per second.  You are reading 100 samples in a loop, so it will take "about one second" to read all the values.

Comment: I had no idea that the sampling rate was 128Hz; it kinda make sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To find the rate at which the loop runs, the easiest would be to toggle a GPIO every cycle then measure that GPIO with an oscilloscope, or possibly using a multimeter with a frequency counter.

Note that the [library](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts/python-circuitpython) I'm assuming you are using doesn't simply take a single sample when you read `chan.value`, but seems to take at least two samples, and possibly takes an inconsistent amount of time to do so. (Note that `chan.value` is implemented as a property, not a variable, meaning that quite a bit of code is executed when you read it. You can check out the source-code [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15/releases))

If you need a consistent sample rate you might get it to work by specifically timing your reads of `chan.value`, or you might need to move to programming in C instead of python.